# Migration from grails 2.4.3 to 3

Tags: grails, migration, grails-3.0

I am upgrading a grails app from 2.4.3 to 3.0.6, but was not able to find the following grails3 compatible plugins [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/wiki/Grails-3-Priority-Upgrade-Plugins):

- hibernate vers 3
- spring-security-ui
- spring-security-oauth2-provider
- quartz2

Where can I find them? Please share you experience.

Comment: This isn't really a specific technical question that is well suited for StackOverflow.  This is probably better suited for posting to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grails-dev-discuss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails 3 plugins are currently located here https://bintray.com/grails/plugins